# mpfr function from Rmpfr package

Tags: r, mpfr

I was trying to print more digits after decimal. So used "mpfr" function. But, why am I getting this result?

```
> mpfr(1/5, 120)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  120   bits 
[1] 0.20000000000000001110223024625156540424
```

Why is the result printing "1110223024625156540424" after the 0s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you gave it a number that was not what you thought it was. The division was done first as a double-precision operation.

```
1/Rmpfr::mpfr(5, 80)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  80   bits 
[1] 2.0000000000000000000000004e-1

> 1/Rmpfr::mpfr(5, 120)
1 'mpfr' number of precision  120   bits 
[1] 2.0000000000000000000000000000000000004e-1
```

My alternate method made a higher precision version of 5 which was then handled by the mpfr-version of `/` (the division function).

See what you get with:

```
methods(`/`)
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why is the 4 printed at the end?

Comment: No, I don't. Perhaps Martin Maechler will wander by. ISTR it's his package.